# How can I switch items in bootstrap carousel by clicking a hyperlinks on webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a fiddle like this http://jsfiddle.net/roxds51h/2/ - there is macbook pro with embedded carousel that contains two pictures. User can switch the pictures by clicking the white dots on the screen. I want to remove the dots and give the possibility of changing pictures by clicking the texts below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
            here is one text //after clicking that 
                             //the first picture should
                             //appear on macbook

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
            here is second text //after clicking that 
                                //the second picture should
                                //appear on macbook
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do that?
Also, now the pictures are changing automatically every couple seconds - how can I disable it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve that with this code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6" data-target="#17" data-slide-to="0">
    here is one text
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" data-target="#17" data-slide-to="1">
    here is second text
  </div>
</div>
```

To disable autoplay change `data-interval="5000"` to `data-interval="false"`.

```
<div id="17" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
```

Removing white dots:

Remove them from HTML, I mean this code:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#17" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
  <li data-target="#17" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks! do you know how to remove the white dots too?

Comment: get rid of ``<ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>`` to remove white dots, check the CodePen above for demo.

Answer (score 1):

you need to swap the data target and warp your text in `<a></a>` tags.

HTML:

```
<section class="introSection">
   <!-- Container -->
   <div class="container macbook">
      <div class="row">
            <div align="center">
               <img alt="" src="http://www.proalab.com/assets/macbookpro.png" class="mackbook_image">
            </div>
            <div class="mackbook">
               <div id="17" class="carousel slide" data-interval="5000" data-ride="carousel">
               <div class="carousel-inner">
                     <div class="item">
                           <img alt="Grey" src="http://www.proalab.com/assets/projects/uanz/uanz1.png" style="display: block;">
                     </div>
                     <div class="item active">
                           <img alt="Grey" src="http://www.proalab.com/assets/projects/uanz/uanz2.png">
                     </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
         <a href="#" data-target="#17" data-slide-to="0">here is one text</a>

   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
         <a href="#" data-target="#17" data-slide-to="1" class="active">here is second text</a>
   </div>
</div>
</section>
```

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/dYmYxz)